# Handouts don't print properly

Tags: beamer, printing, pgfpages

I have been unable to print handouts --- multiple slides per page with border around each. And it just does not work. I tried compiling with xelatex and latex (both almost default installs on Ubuntu 10.12).

How do I set it right? Below is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,english,professionalfonts,smaller,handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=Black]{structure}

\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{.}{./images/}}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\date{}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my infolines theme}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{\underline{\textbf{Author} }}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}Title~---~\insertshorttitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}

\newcommand{\footlineextra}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[yshift=2ex,anchor=south east] at (current page.south east) {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace{2ex}#1};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }

\newcommand{\footlineleft}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[yshift=2ex,anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace{2ex}#1};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }

%}}}

\title{\newline Title \newline}
\institute[Institute]{\Large{Institute}\newline \newline \normalsize{\textbf{Some text} normal text\newline \textbf{Some text} normal text\newline \textbf{Some text}}}

\mode<handout>{
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
  \usetheme{default}
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!5}
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Slide 1}

\pause

ONE

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Slide 2}

\pause

TWO

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Slide 3}

\pause

THREE

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Slide 4}

\pause

FOUR

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you get errors with this code? What do you mean you can't print the handouts? Nothing comes out in your pdf?

Comment: I advise you to update your TeX distribution. Look for the older posts like this collection of older posts on [how to install TeXLive 2012 in Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=installing+texlive+in+ubuntu&submit=search).

Comment: @hpesoj626 the code compiles properly. But the resultant PDF handout is not proper (2 on 1 OR 4 on 1)

Comment: What do regard as wrong with the output?  It compiles fine for me, placing two frames on one page above each other with a (thin) border.  There is space to the left and right, because of the `landscape` option you pass to `\pgfpagesuselayout`.  Removing this will make the two frames essentially fill the page.  Adding `\pgfsetlinewidth{4pt}` to your border code before `\pgfusepath{stroke}` will give you thicker (more visible) border.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, the problem was with the compiler. The same code compiled with xelatex produces incorrect handouts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. After a lot of looking around, I could pinpoint the problem. When you compile the code with xelatex, the handout is not proper. You need to compile it with pdflatex to get the handouts properly.

Answer (score 2):

`pgfpages` seems to be running into issues with Beamer, at least according to

https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/183

(I'm having the same problem). What I do now is `ps2dpf` the `latex/dvips` output (without `pgfpages`) - which will scale up to the right presentation size - and then run a small `pdflatex` job on it, calling `pdfpages`

```
\includepdf[nup=1x2,pages=1-last,delta=1.5 1.5,frame=true]{0.pdf}
```

(or change nup as desired).  Hope that helps.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can format your code using the `{}` button in the edit window or by indenting code rows by four empty spaces

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/http://), particularly at pdfnup. Its argument list can be intimidating, but it is extremely flexible. AFAIU, internally it uses LaTeX to do the dirty job of placing multiple pages on one sheet.

Comment: Sure, this seems to be a solution. But I dont know why latex/ xelatex wont be able to produce handouts in the desired configuration